how can i setup swipe fucntion in androidstudio kotlin
so when I started my project first I modified the MainActivity class inside the OnCreate to initialize the functions for its activity_main.xml (imagebuttons recyclerview background change with switch etc.) that was my main activity. Then I had an idea of adding swipe feature to go from the main layout to second layout by swiping left to right. I created the second layout the same way as the Mainactivity was created. I created the class and then connected the xml with the class
(tools:context=".FoldersActivity") and initialized the functions.
I came across ViewPager2 in the Internet but I could not find any solutions to make what I needed. Thanks.

First add ViewPager2 in activity_main This will act as the container that allows users to swipe between the layouts
activity_main
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Instead of creating separate activities for each layout, you'll create two fragments. MainFragment for your main layout.FoldersFragment for the second layout.
MainFragment.kt
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Initialize your functions for Main Layout here
    }
}

FoldersFragment.kt
class FoldersFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_folders) {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Initialize your functions for Folders Layout here
    }
}

Now we can set up the ViewPager2 to handle swiping between the fragments. Create an adapter that tells ViewPager2 which fragment to display.
MainActivty.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Reference to the ViewPager2 in activity_main.xml
        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

        // List of fragments to swipe between
        val fragments = listOf(MainFragment(), FoldersFragment())

        // Set up the adapter
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this, fragments)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
    }
}

ViewPagerAdapter.kt
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    activity: AppCompatActivity,
    private val fragments: List<Fragment>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    // Returns the number of fragments
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragments.size

    // Returns the fragment to display for the current page
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }
}



What about the fragment layout xml's? should I just copy and paste activity xml layout code into fragment 1 xml and folders xml code into fragment 2? And will all of the code work in fragment same as it works now in my activity class?

Yes, just create activity_main.xml and folders_activity.xml layouts, Modify the UI based on your requirementa
